# how to get point on axis of a line in distance d

Tags: vector, gps

I have two points A,B so they form a line AB. I'd like to know how to calculate a point in distance d on axis of this line.

This question gives the answer for rotating a point in 2D: [c# - how to move point a given distance d (and get a new coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598858/c-sharp-how-to-move-point-a-given-distance-d-and-get-a-new-coordinates)

So I can get the mid of line AB and rotate it. But I need to find out, by how many degrees I need to rotate - 90 or 180.

How can I do it in 3D/gps coords?

http://postimage.org/image/bt9zdway3/

any ideas?

Comment: Now that I thought more about it, the simple answer I gave below completely breaks down in spherical coordinates. I added the link to the picture you drew to your post.

Comment: I would be satisfied with planar solution for this problem.

Comment: But it would be horribly wrong with GPS coordinates.

Comment: this solution should work for short distances (less than 5km). I think in this case spherical nature of GPS coordinates should not affect result significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've calculated center C of line AB then then translated C to desired distance C' and rotated C' around original C. Probably there is easier way but it worked for me