# Moving object a given distance to the direction its facing c#

Tags: c#, geometry, position, 2d, orientation

If I have an object and I know its (x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll). How can I move it distance D in the same direction its facing? (it has to move the same direction it is facing) then get the new point.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How can a point b facing something?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant and object that I know its center point, edited the post to make it clear

Comment: First determine what the forward vector would be if there was no rotation. Then rotate that vector by the yaw and pitch (roll doesn't effect where you're facing if it's last). That's your new forward vector; multiply it by D.

Comment: @Jeff when you say multiply it by D do you mean (new yaw * D, new pitch * D)? if so, what will the new position will be (I mean the new x, y, z)?

Comment: This answer solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598894/8072779